# Como usar 2 valores em uma propriedade css

Tags: css

Boa tarde, quero que minha String seja formatada como **Bold** e *Italic*. No meu arquivo de css está assim:

```
font-style: italic bold;
```

Não funciona. Já tentei de várias maneiras e não consigo. Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use apenas `font` e não font-style e adicione o tamanho e qual a fonte a ser utilizada.

**Exemplo:**

```
font: italic bold 15px Georgia;
```

Você pode ver funcionando [aqui](https://fiddle.jshell.net/sp5x208s/)

[Referência na W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp)

Comment: Sem sucesso :(.

Comment: editei a resposta. vê se funciona agora

Comment: Show! Muito Obrigado.